# Sharepoint online custom navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online

I there a built-in way i can create navigation links as in picture below on modern sharepoint pages using Quick Links or any other apps?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just choose Cascading style for the navigation. This is in settings-> Change the look-> navigation:

[image] [image]

[image]

Update:

You could achieve this with the modern script web part:

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

The code demo use in the web part: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

```
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for taking time and answering my question.  I am not looking this for the top navigation. The screenshot i shared is the one currently on my site top navigation bar.  I am trying to see if it is possible to achieve this kind of cascading navigation on the main portion of the page using either quick links or any other apps.

Comment: Qucik links web part cannot achieve this. Moder script web part would be feasible to you. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To piggy-back off the answer provided by Michael Han_MSFT above, after you have selected the "Cascading" menu type, you will want to set up your links as sub-links to have the sub-layers of the menu.

[image]